# Unqualified lookup and (maybe-)dependent base classes

Tags: c++

Consider the following program:

```
template <typename T>
struct t
{
    struct base { void f1(); };
    struct derived : base
    {
        void f2()
        {
            f1();
        }
    };
};
```

In `derived::f2`, unqualified lookup is used to find `f1`. Will `base` be searched? Will `base::f1` be found? Is `base` a dependent type?

Please substantiate your answers with quotes from the standard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, `base` is dependent so `f1` is not found. In C++03 this was clearified by the [addition](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#108) `14.6.1/2d` (which did not exist in C++98) and in C++0x this is directly stated by `14.6.2.1/6` (n3126).

Dependency of it is important, because the following is possible

```
// for T = int, f1 does not exist.
template<> struct t<int>::base { };
```

Comment: Ah, that's the stone I missed, I had forgotten about the possibility to only specialize a sub-class of a template type.

Comment: @Matthieu I don't understand your question.

Comment: @litb: `void f(int); template <typename T> g() { f(4.0); } void f(double);`, `g` should invoke `f(int)` here (if I recall correctly) whereas in the case exposed by avakar the base could be specialized after the definition of `f2`... isn't there something like this on look-up to prevent further includes to somehow "corrupt" a method definition.

Comment: @Matthieu the base class could be specialized after the definition of `f2` but not after instantiation of `A<X>::derived`. When `derived` is instantiated, then in turn the correct specialization of `base` is selected and (possibly) instantiated. A rule says that after `base` was instantiated, no explicit specialization that would have been selected as the specialization cannot be provided anymore. So after you say for example `sizeof (t<Foo>::derived)`, `t<Foo>::base` cannot be explicitly specialized anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't fit into a comment box...

gcc rejects the code:

`there are no arguments to 'f1' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'f1' must be available`.

However introducing `this->` before `f1` makes it dependent and then the compilation works.

As far as my experience has shown, the same behavior apply to:

- types (you have to `typedef` them again)
- methods (you need to use `using base::f1` or `this->f1`)

And I have seen this behavior in:

- gcc 3.4
- VC++ 9
- VC++ 10

And now we can wait for standardistas to get exact quotes from the standard.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Actually, introducing `this->` before `f1` makes the search use a member name lookup instead of an unqualified lookup, so the name is found. I'm asking, because I'm trying to compile our codebase with clang and it failed on something which can be reduced to the sample in the question (whereas MSVC and apparently gcc-4.3 accepted it).

Comment: MSVC does not correctly implement template support (it doesn't implement the two-phases look-up mandated by the standard). I shall test with gcc-4.3 --> it's accepted (gcc-4.3.2) I wonder if it's been solved since.

Comment: @avakar: I am excited to see that many people are interested in Clang. I am myself and I really think it could become a great compiler with time (and effort).